# Blocking NFC-Tags without metal

Tags: nfc

I got this NFC-Tag and I try to do something, so that this tag can't be recognized by any nfc-tag-reader anymore. But I want to easily change this state, so that I can easily 'free' the nfc-tag so that it is working again.

What would be the best solution for this?

I thought about aluminium or other metal to place on my nfc-tag. This would work, but is there any other solution for my problem, not using any metal?

I am not an electrical engineer, so maybe my quesion is kind of stupid, I can't evaluate.

**EDIT:** I don't want to use metal, because if I place it on my nfc-tag,  I can't see my tag anymore. Metal is very opaque. This is one of the reasons I am looking for different solutions.

Comment: Aluminum foil or thin metal is cheap. Why not use metal? There is no reason to look for another solution when the obvious one is right there.

Comment: Engineers don't usually like "I don't want to use solution X" unless a reason is given. This mostly comes up here with "I don't want to use a microcontroller".

Comment: Seal it in a plastic bag and park it in a bucket of (salt) water.

Comment: Re Your Edit: You can put a sticker or write on the metal or any number of things.

Comment: @Passerby That is unfortunately no option for me. Because I want to be able to block many different nfc-tags with just one blocking-device.

Comment: Are shop-*lifting* questions off-topic?

Comment: @Transistor hmm that's the direction I started to read from the question combined with comments - started with one tag then suddenly many...

Comment: This is absolutely not about shoplifting. It is not about rfid-tags (which are used in shops where I am from at least). Well maybe the blocking-mechanism would be the same for them? It is for an entirely differen purpose, which is hard to explain and part of an secret start-up idea. Also, why would I want them to see the nfc-tag when I want to steal something with it..wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @electricNewbie As conductive [transparent aluminum](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Transparent_aluminum) has not been invented yet, you may might be able to use a thin metal mesh to shield the device - of course, the visibility of any markings on the device will depend on the density of the mesh and the size of the markings.

Comment: @Andrew sure, but other transparent conductors do exist

Comment: @matt stupid question, how can we have E-field in the medium, which is necessary for the propagation of light, i.e. for transparency, but still have conduction? Only way I can think of is placing the conducting elements sparsely enough so that visible wavelengths pass, while radio doesn't - which is basically why you can look into your microwave oven or through salt water. Anything else that does that I missed? By the way, are we sure classical low frequency NFC would be blocked by aluminum foil? NFC=magnetic coupling ≠ radio propagation

Comment: @electricNewbie Re: "secret startup idea" I'm sorry, this sounds all too much like this Dilbert situation: http://dilbert.com/strip/2015-09-11

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thats a good question, one that I can't answer. But transparent conductors, such as [ITO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_tin_oxide), are a crucial element in flat panel displays.

Comment: Ah OK,but these as far as I can guess probably have pretty high resistance, being as thin as they are, and limited aperiodic dampening of waves traveling through the sheer thinness

Comment: You can try holding it flat up against a dielectric puck. That may de-tune it sufficiently that it cannot be read.

Comment: You would want something with a high relative permitivitty. Maybe an alumina disc? Or put it in a container of ethylene glycol? http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/dielectric-constants-strengths.htm